# MongoDB sort documents by specified element in array

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a collection like that:

```
[
  { 
    student: "a", 
    package: [ 
      {name: "one", createdAt: "2021-10-12T00:00:00", active: true}, 
      {name: "two", createdAt: "2021-10-13T00:00:00", active: false}, 
      {name: "three", createdAt: "2021-10-14T00:00:00", active: false} 
    ] 
  },
  { 
    student: "b", 
    package: [ 
      {name: "one", createdAt: "2021-10-16T00:00:00", active: true}, 
      {name: "two", createdAt: "2021-10-17T00:00:00", active: false}, 
      {name: "three", createdAt: "2021-10-18T00:00:00", active: false} 
    ] 
  },
  { 
    student: "c", 
    package: [ 
      {name: "one", createdAt: "2021-10-10T00:00:00", active: true}, 
      {name: "two", createdAt: "2021-10-17T00:00:00", active: false}, 
      {name: "three", createdAt: "2021-10-18T00:00:00", active: false} 
    ] 
  }
]
```

I have no idea how can I do a query (Mongodb) to sort this collection based on the createdAt with **active: true** in the package array?

The expectation looks like this:

```
[
  { 
    student: "c", 
    package: [ 
      {name: "one", createdAt: "2021-10-10T00:00:00", active: true}, 
      ...
    ] 
  },
  { 
    student: "a", 
    package: [ 
      {name: "one", createdAt: "2021-10-12T00:00:00", active: true},
      ... 
    ] 
  },
  { 
    student: "b", 
    package: [ 
      {name: "one", createdAt: "2021-10-16T00:00:00", active: true}, 
      ...
    ] 
  },
]
```

Could anyone help me with this? The idea comes up to my mind just to use the code to sort it, but is it possible to use a query MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- creates a sort-key for each document, this is the latest date of the active package members (the $reduce does, this keeping the max date)
- sort by it
- unset to remove this extra key

*for descended or ascedent, you can chage the `$gt` with `$lt` and the sort 1, with sort -1. depending on what you need. If you use `$lt` replace `"0"` also with a max string like `"9"`. Or if you have real dates, with a min or max date.

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49af)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"sort-key": 
     {"$reduce": 
       {"input": "$package",
        "initialValue": "0",
         "in": 
         {"$cond": 
           [{"$and": 
            ["$$this.active", {"$gt": ["$$this.createdAt", "$$value"]}]},
             "$$this.createdAt", "$$value"]}}}}},
 {"$sort": {"sort-key": 1}},
 {"$unset": ["sort-key"]}])
```

Comment: Thank you, bro! I love your way!

Comment: I've upvoted because the effort and I like reduce way but this not sort by `active`. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yl15B52zSaZ)

Comment: yes it doesnt sorts the array, only the collection. question was confusing a bit, list meant the collection i think, i wasnt sure also. @JF solution sorts the array by active fist i think, if you need that use the other solution. Because the above solution doesnt change the array at all.

Comment: I'm sorry for making you guys confuse! Basically, I don't need to sort the array! I just want to sort the object based on the createdAt date of the active package only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First `$unwind` to  deconstruct the array ang get each value.
- Then `$sort` by active.
- `$group` to get the initial data but sorted.
- And last `$sort` again by `createdAt`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$package"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "package.createdAt": {
        "$toDate": "$package.createdAt"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "package.active": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "student": {
        "$first": "$student"
      },
      "package": {
        "$push": "$package"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "package.createdAt": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DKb_btyY0Du)

Also, to do the sorting, is better if `createdAt` is a `Date` field, otherwise you should parse to date. Like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/95eXwWyu093)